# Vue multiple components in one package/file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, node-modules

let's say i want to create a UI Package, how can I put multiple components into one single JS file?

Normally I would have my different components in different files:

```
import ButtonText from '../ButtonText.vue'
import ButtonIcon from '../ButtonIcon .vue'
import ButtonLayout from '../ButtonLayout.vue'
```

but I want to put all my Button components in a single file, for reuseability etc. so i can import things when I need them

```
import {ButtonText, ButtonIcon, ButtonLayout } from '../ButtonPackage.vue'
```

how would my ButtonPackage.vue/.js File look like?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. I hope it's not possible because this is against everything about having components in the first place. You just want to create a huge mess in the script section and probably a few thousands of lines of code to scroll. Why?

Answer (score 3):

In `ButtonPackage.js` file you import all components, and export them as an object.

```
import ButtonText from '../ButtonText.vue'
import ButtonIcon from '../ButtonIcon .vue'
import ButtonLayout from '../ButtonLayout.vue'

export {ButtonText, ButtonIcon, ButtonLayout }
```

Then in a component you import them as needed:

```
import { ButtonText } from '../ButtonPackage.js'
```

Answer (score 2):

The key is to export all components in one file:

```
import ButtonText from "./ButtonText";
import ButtonIcon from "./ButtonIcon";
import ButtonLayout from "./ButtonLayout";
export { ButtonText, ButtonIcon, ButtonLayout };
```

So when you want to use any of them:

```
import {
  ButtonText,
  ButtonIcon,
  ButtonLayout,
} from "./components/ButtonPackage";
```

Here is a demo I created:

https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-oskar-gper1?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark