# vue multiple components in a single file

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-script-setup

in vue documents I saw "Namespaced Components" in "script setup" guide it writes:

> You can use component tags with dots like <Foo.Bar> to refer to components nested under object properties. This is useful when you import multiple components from a single file:

```
<script setup>
import * as Form from './form-components'
</script>

<template>
  <Form.Input>
    <Form.Label>label</Form.Label>
  </Form.Input>
</template>
```

I wanted to know in this example what will the form-component look like, and what is the correct use case for such a component, does it have anything to do with "slot" or not.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66200383/vue-multiple-components-in-one-package-file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, **form-components** refers to a `.js` file that seems to be exporting single-file components (`.vue`).

**form-components.js**

```
export { default as Label } from './form-label.vue'
export { default as Input } from './form-input.vue'
```

You can then access these components via:

```
import * as Form from './form-components'
```

However, I recommend using a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) methodology, as it is better interpreted by IDEs.

```
import { Input, Label } from './form-components'
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, can you tell me why we might want to create a js file and export from there? what is the purpose?

Comment: This is to make it easier to import many components from the same directory at once. Usually, these components are exported from an `index.js` file.

Comment: IDEs shouldn't have problems with `*` imports. But it's easier to use destructuring because of autoimports. And when an import needs a namespace to avoid collisions or ambiguousness, the name can be changed as `Label as FormLabel`.